# Make first H1 letter of each word larger and colored for a single H1

Tags: html, text, colors, size

I've got a h1 line of 5 words and I want to increase the size of the 3rd, 4th and 5th initial letters only, underline them and then make them a different color.

I've done it but WC3 says my code is invalid on all attributes and elements in each case of size, underlining and color.

Here's what works in the browsers but won't validate:

`<p><h1>Welcome to <br /><font size="120%" color=Red><u>M</u></font>y <font size=120% color=Red><u>F</u></font>vourite
   <font size=120% color=Red><u>W</u></font>ebsite</h1></p>`

It's giving me my only errors (15 in all) on this design.

Please can anyone assist with the HTML and or CSS to fix this so that it validates.

I have tried variations for size and color and though they work in the browsers, they will not validate.

Thank you :)

Comment: All I can recommend is the `:first-letter` pseudo-class, but that won't expand to additional words. Just may have to use jQuery/JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 6):

They won't validate cause the font tag was deprecated long ago, and thus all of its parameters,

You can use this in CSS:

```
h1 {
margin:5px;
}
#title span {
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #c13636;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And wrap the word to be highlighted in span tags:

```
<span>TEST</span>
```

Applied to your code:

```
<h1 id="title">Welcome to <br /><span>M</span>y <span>F</span>avourite <span>W</span>ebsite</h1>
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/SBbcu/

Comment: Probably a mis-type, but don't forget you'll need a '.' before your className in your CSS

Comment: Might be neater to do `<h1 id="title">Welcome to <br /><span>M</span> ..` and `#title span { .. }`

Comment: Nice thought, I will amend my answer.

Comment: Hang on.. there's an <h1> inside a <p>. That won't validate.

Comment: Well then we can just add padding to the <h1> to act like a <p>

Comment: Yeah that'll do it. I'll stop picking at your otherwise perfectly fine answer now!

Comment: @ScottBrown - Haha, no problem man, I needed put right on that :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<font></font> and <u></u>
```

are deprecated. Use a `<span></span>` with CSS applied to it.

Comment: Indeed, `span:first-letter{font-size:x-large;text-decoration:underline;}` and `<h1><span>word</span> <span>word</span></h1>` may be best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `span` element with a `style` attribute, as in:

```
<span style="font-size: 120%; color: red; text-decoration: underline;">M</span>
```

Alternatively, define CSS classes for the various combinations and use those instead.

Comment: Using `class` is preferred over `style`.

Comment: I totally agree, but I was just giving the OP the simplest answer to his dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

You have some invalid tags `<font>` and `<u>`.

I would do something like this to validate and clean up your code:

```
<style>
    .big {
         font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    .red {
         color: red;
    }
</style>

<h2>Welcome to</h2>
<h1>
    <span class="big red">M</span>y 
    <span class="big red">F</span>avorite 
    <span class="big red">W</span>ebsite
</h1>
```

or even:

```
<style>
    h1 span:first-letter {
        font-size: 1.2em;
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<h2>Welcome to</h2>
<h1>
    <span>My</span>
    <span>Favorite</span> 
    <span>Website</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, as a summary

- can't have  inside a
- don't use `<font>` or `<u>`
- HTML is for markup, CSS for styling

With "pure" HTML/CSS you have multiple possibilities to achieve what you're after. Here are couple variations. You probably should add `class` attributes to `span` elements but I've omitted them here for brevity.

1°

HTML file:

```
<h1>Welcome to <span>M</span>y <span>F</span>vourite <span>W</span>ebsite</h1>
```

CSS file:

```
h1 span {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

---

2°

HTML file:

```
<h1>Welcome to <span>My</span> <span>Favourite</span> <span>Website</span></h1>
```

CSS file:

```
h1 span:first-letter {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, will try out all you've said - very helpful (and fast replies too) :)